# Problem with installing plugins in Eclipse (installed requirements)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, nios

i´ve some trouble with installing a plugin in Eclipse. I´m using Quartus Prime Lite Edition (v. 18.1) NIOS II EDS (Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)). This is a customized version from Intel for fpga programming.

My Problem:

When I try to install the plugin, it fails, because it could not find the installed requirements. 
When I tried to install via "Install New Software" or via command line, i get the following message:

`C:\Users\maemeba>"C:\intelFPGA_lite\18.1\nios2eds\bin\eclipse_nios2\eclipsec.exe" -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://welding1.wittag.net:9090/axivion/axivion-eclipse-plugin/repository -installIU com.axivion.aclipse.feature.feature.group
Installing com.axivion.aclipse.feature.feature.group 6.9.13.02186.
Installation failed.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.                                                                                                                        Software being installed: Axivion Eclipse Feature 6.9.13.02186 (com.axivion.aclipse.feature.feature.group 6.9.13.02186)
 Missing requirement: Axivion Eclipse Feature 6.9.13.02186 (com.axivion.aclipse.feature.feature.group 6.9.13.02186) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2.1.0' but it could not be found
Application failed, log file location: C:\Users\maemeba\.altera.sbt4e\18.1.0.625-windows64\configuration\1579076958115.log`
[Logfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkwVM.png)

I´ve checked, if the missing requirements are aviable, and they are there. See [Eclipse Installed Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RtI9.png)

The support for the Quartus product can't help me.

Do you know any solutions?

Many thanks, 
kind regards
bastian7032

Comment: Hey did you check that your PC can contact the URL http://welding1.wittag.net:9090/axivion/axivion-eclipse-plugin/repository. Maybe there is problem with a firewall at your side on port 9090?

Comment: Hey, 
thank you for your help. 
Yes, the PC can contact the URL.

Comment: Your Eclipse is quite old; your are more than 4 years and 9 releases behind. Can you reproduce this issue with the current Eclipse version?

Comment: Hi! As the stack trace sais that "'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2.1.0' but it could not be found" maybe you could try to install the equinox p2 installer and try again. I think that this is the correct version for your eclipse Mars 2: https://archive.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-Mars.2-201602121500/index.php

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I cannot update my Eclipse version, because its a customized version from Intel. So i have to use this version.

@JaimeS I´ve tried to install the equinox p2 installer, but i cannot install it. :/ 

Strangely, the equinox p2 is already installed, as you can see in the Eclipse Installed Details.

Comment: @JaimeS I´ve tried to install the equinox p2 installer. When I installed the equinox p2, Eclipse doesnt start anymore. So i have to delete my Eclipse folder in /user/

Comment: Hi,
I just wanted to let you know, that I have solved the problem with the 3rd party plugin.

I was able to solve the problem by copying, pasting and merging files of the 3rd party plugin and the NIOS2 Eclipse. Unfortunately, an installation via "Install New Software" is still not possible.
Regards
Bastian